# Can we add a simple search to the "vote to close as duplicate" feature on the iOS app, like on desktop?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, ios-app

On my phone right now, so very briefly...

VTC (e.g. as dupe) on mobile iOS app has no simple search like the regular desktop site.

That would be a nice addition.

Comment: I, of course, only ever think of these things when I'm stuck on my phone for the week ;)

Comment: I'd vote myself to close as a dupe... but I'm on my phone ;)